# URL rewrites - routing in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a www.example.com domain, and I need it to make it URL friendly. That domain need to be in multilanguage, like this:

```
http://{language}.example.com/restufullurls
```

How is that achievable in Backbone/Marrionette, only using routes?

Comment: not sure it possible. looks like you need to use require js i18n plugin to load language sets and then init application

Comment: Backbone doesn't care about your subdomain and defaults to using the hash for routing. Simply parse the `location` and set the appropriate language, there shouldn't be a need to change anything in the router.

Comment: Would you care to provide small example, how do you envision of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a config file somewhere:

```
var config = {
   lang: 'en',
   domain: 'example.com'
};
```

Then make a base model that will rewrite the url of all models. What this does is rewrites the URL you specify in a model by appending the correct URL from the config file:

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function(){
      this.url = 'http://' + config.lang + '.' + config.domain + '/' + this.url;
   }
});
```

Then every time you need a  new Model, you can extend the Base

```
var SomeModel = BaseModel.extend({
   url: 'some/rest/url'
});
```

If you need to switch the language just do

```
config.lang = 'new-language';
```

If you would like to use the same URL as the file is being served from just do:

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function(){
      this.url = window.location.origin + '/' + this.url;
   }
});
```

Comment: I have marked the answer. I will give this a try, it looks like a solid approach. Thank you. I will provide my update here, and the steps that I took.